# how to automate sending commands using SSH factory

Tags: java, ssh

I am using ssh factory to automate the logins. I have to automate logins till 4 gateways and send commands and get output's of it. I have successfully automated till 3 gateways. Now i have to fire command "telnet remote_ip" to get into the 4th gateway. Where i am using telnet sessions for this 4th gateway alone since i need to fire "telnet ip", since it is using telnet protocol over here. But for the previous 3 gateway's i've used ssh sessions. But it is not firing this "telnet ip" command. Can some1 help me regarding this?.

```
Below is the code, where i am trying to automate it.

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.jscape.inet.ssh.Ssh;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshAdapter;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshConnectedEvent;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshDataReceivedEvent;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshDisconnectedEvent;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshException;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshScript;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshSession;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.SshTask;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.connection.channels.SessionClient;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.connection.channels.SessionRequests;
import com.jscape.inet.ssh.util.SshParameters;
import com.jscape.inet.telnet.Telnet;
import com.jscape.inet.telnet.TelnetException;
import com.jscape.inet.telnet.TelnetListener;
import com.jscape.inet.telnet.TelnetScript;
import com.jscape.inet.telnet.TelnetSession;
import com.jscape.inet.telnet.TelnetTask;

public class SshScriptTutorial extends SshAdapter {
   public SshScriptTutorial() {}

   public void executeSshScript(String hostname, String username, String password)
      throws SshException, IOException, InterruptedException, TelnetException
   {
      // assumes that SSH shell prompt is ">" .. this MUST match exactly 
      String shellPrompt = ">";
      String shellPrompt1 = ":";

      // initialize and create new Ssh instance
      SshParameters sshParams = new SshParameters(hostname,username,password);
      Ssh ssh = new Ssh(sshParams);

      // register this class to receive Ssh events
      ssh.addSshListener(this);

      // create new script object and bind to the given ssh object
      SshScript script = new SshScript(ssh);

      // add tasks to script object
      script.addTask(new SshTask(shellPrompt, "show host", shellPrompt));
      script.addTask(new SshTask(shellPrompt, "ssh ssgpun", shellPrompt1)); // 2nd g/w 
      script.addTask(new SshTask(shellPrompt1, "password", shellPrompt));

      script.addTask(new SshTask(shellPrompt, "net ip", shellPrompt1)); // 3rd gateway
      script.addTask(new SshTask(shellPrompt1, "username", shellPrompt1));
      script.addTask(new SshTask(shellPrompt1, "password", shellPrompt));

 // till this it is working

      // connect to SSH server and execute script
      ssh.connect();

      // wait until last task is complete
      while(!script.isComplete()) {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
         } catch(Exception e) {
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
         }
      }

      // disconnect from server
//      ssh.disconnect();
```

//****
    Here i am trying to get into the last remote server using command "telnet ip" using telnet session since it is involving telnet protocol. But it is not firing this command itself. So, can anybody help me regarding this. How to do?... I have even tried using ssh sessions for this "telnet ip" and for username and pass. If i use ssh session for this 4th gateway, i am able to automate only "telnet ip" and it is asking for login name, and login name is not automated. So, i have tried both ssh sessions and telnet sessions. I dont know what is the prob or how to solve it.

Kindly help...

//****

```
      // create new Telnet instance
      Telnet telnet = new Telnet("10.228.128.33");

   // create new TelnetScript instance and bind to Telnet instance
      TelnetScript script_t = new TelnetScript(telnet);

   // create a task that waits for login prompt and submits username
      TelnetTask username_t = new TelnetTask(shellPrompt1,"switchind", shellPrompt1);

   // create task that waits for password prompt and submits password
      TelnetTask password_t = new TelnetTask(shellPrompt1, "Indore123", shellPrompt);

   // add tasks to script
      script_t.addTask(username_t);
      script_t.addTask(password_t);

   // connect to telnet server … script is executed automatically
      telnet.connect();
   }

   public void connected(SshConnectedEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Connected to host: " + event.getHost());
   }

   public void disconnected(SshDisconnectedEvent event) {
      System.out.println("Disconnected from host: " + event.getHost());
   }

   public void dataReceived(SshDataReceivedEvent event) {
       System.out.print(event.getData());
   }  

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      try 
      {
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

         String hostname = "host_ip";
         String username = "username";

         System.out.print("Enter password: ");
         String password = reader.readLine();            

         SshScriptTutorial tutorial = new SshScriptTutorial();
         tutorial.executeSshScript(hostname, username, password);

      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Posting a *minimal* code example to illustrate your problem is a better idea than pasting lots of code. In addition, you should look at the post, and perhaps format the code blocks so it's not split on the comment. Using full words like `someone` is a good idea; it shows that you've taken the time to think about, research and articulate your problem.